# Struts beginner libraries

Tags: java, apache, struts2, tomcat6

I am beginner to struts. I used few sample hello world applications. First of all I executed hello world example of struts 2.0.1 then I downloaded latest libraries and tried to create struts app. But it couldn't be deployed. My downloaded version was 2.2. Then I had to change the libraries a bit. Instead of commons-logging used in 2.0.1 I had to use commons-io commons-file-upload javaasist. Then only i could run it. However all other codes were same. Why is it so? Where could i get the details regarding this. Is there any link or reference by which i can know the core libraries to be used in all applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) and one of the [struts 2 maven archetypes](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html) to start a project.  For example, after installing Maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B \
                   -DgroupId=your.group.id \
                   -DartifactId=your.app.name \
                   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts \
                   -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-convention \
                   -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.1
```

will create a sample struts 2 project for you with the [conventions plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/convention-plugin.html) enabled.

You can also find a list of core dependencies here:

http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/struts2-core/dependencies.html